# iPhone, string from utf8 xml with wrong characters

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, utf-8, rss

I have to display the text contained into an xml file I get from the web. The file starts with:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...

then there is the text node, written like this:

<text><![CDATA[E ancora, il fascino delle cittÃ  del nord, che con la primavera conquistano ore luce, o di isole dove la Pasqua Ã¨ un rito rimasto fedele nel tempo.Pasqua Ã¨ un'occasione pe...]]></text>

Is this well utf-8 formatted text?

I've tried all of this, but still can't replace "Ã" with "à" and "Ã¨" with "è":

```
text = ^the string from above^
NSData* data_text = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* text_c3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data_text bytes] length:[data_text length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

const char* utfstring = "E ancora, il fascino delle cittÃ  del nord,";// [text UTF8String];
NSString* text_c1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:utfstring];
NSString* text_converted = [NSString stringWithCString:utfstring encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: in xml is there à or Ã ?

Comment: `utfstring` is not a UTF8String string, it is just a 8-bit string, probably in the internal `kCFStringEncodingMacRoman` format which does have encodings for these characters in the range 129-255. In unicode these characters would be composed of multiple (in this case two) 8-bit codes,

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to tell from your question whether the CDATA part is properly UTF-8 encoded. Since encoded data is binary data, you would need to post the binary data (i.e. in a hexadecimal representation) and not some text.

Furthermore, all your code samples depend on the source code file being stored with the correct encoding, which again cannot be determined from your question.

I propose you use a decent XML parser to parse the XML data, such as the built-in *NSXMLParser* class. When it encounters the CDATA section, it will call your delegate and pass the text as binary data in UTF-8 encoding, no matter what the original encoding was. You can then convert it into a string:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)cdataBlock
{
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: [cdataBlock bytes]];

    // do something with the text...
}
```

And make sure you retrieve the XML file as binary data and pass it to the XML parser as XML data. If not, you will have unnecessary decodings and encodings and you are likely to damage the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourURL.com"];

```
//NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&json_data=%@",[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"createInvoice\":{\"client_id\":\"%@\",\"address\":\"\",\"invoice_title\":\"%@\",\"number\":\"\",\"date\":\"%@\",\"due_date\":\"%@\",\"late_fee\":\"\",\"schedule_date\":\"%@\",\"po_number\":\"\",\"status\":\"paid\",\"notes\":\"invoice notes\",\"terms\":\"invoice terms\",\"items\":[{\"name\":\"Test4\",\"type\":\"Product\",\"description\":\"\",\"unit_cost\":\"15\",\"quantity\":\"100\",\"discount\":\"10\",\"discount_type\":\"Percent\",\"tax1_name\":\"\",\"tax1_type\":\"\",\"tax2_name\":\"\",\"tax2_type\":\"\",\"tax1_percent\":\"\",\"tax2_percent\":\"\"}]}}",selected_Client_ID,invoiceTitleTxtFld.text,invoiveDateTxtFld.text,invoiceDueDateTxtFld.text,scheduleOnTxtFld.text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&json_data=%@",[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"updateInvoice\":{\"invoice_id\":\"%@\",\"client_id\":\"60105\",\"address\":\"ABS\",\"invoice_title\": \"%@\",\"number\":\"inv-7774 new\",\"date\":\"2012-03-30\",\"due_date\":\"2012-04-30\",\"late_fee\":\"\",\"schedule_date\":\"2012-03-31\",\"po_number\":\"PO-7770\",\"status\":\"paid\",\"notes\":\"invoice notes\",\"terms\":\"invoice terms\",\"items\":[{\"name\":\"Test4\",\"type\":\"Product\",\"description\":\"Test4 desc\",\"unit_cost\":\"15\",\"quantity\":\"100\",\"discount\":\"10\",\"discount_type\":\"Percent\",\"tax1_name\":\"\",\"tax1_type\":\"\",\"tax2_name\":\"\",\"tax2_type\":\"\",\"tax1_percent\":\"\",\"tax2_percent\":\"\"}]}}",delegate.invoice_ID,invoiceTitleTxtFld.text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSData *json_data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: json_data];
NSLog(@"%@",json_data);
//[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [json_data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[jsonRequest stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                      allowLossyConversion:YES]];

//  [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[request autorelease] delegate:self];
```

NSUrlsConnection *conn_InvEdit = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                      initWithRequest:request 
                                      delegate:self];

```
// Successful connection.
if (conn_InvEdit) {

    // [self initSpinner];
    // [self spinBegin];

    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.receivedData=data;
    [data release];
} 
// Unsuccessful connection.
else {

}  
// Clean up
[url release];
[request release];
// Close keypad.

Try with this code, If you still have any problem then send me your complete question at  akram.khan@mail.vinove.com. I'll send you sample app with solution.
```

Answer (score 0):

...

add tagging like this

...

and use

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

and [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [json_data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[jsonRequest stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                      allowLossyConversion:YES]];